# Cannot install in VM or through wubi

Tags: wubi, windows-7, virtualization

I've tried VMs and now Wubi, and whenever i use a VM to install, i get "must run in low graphics mode" with a black screen or it freezes afterward.

When I install on my real machine through wubi, I reboot into Ubuntu, and I get the following:

> "completing the Ubuntu installation"
>
> "For more installation boot
>
> options, press 'esc' now"
>
> "0"
>
> "_"

It stays on this screen for as long as I have patience (think an hour or more) and then I just restart and boot into Windows.

All i have to do is download the appropriate wubi.exe and it does everything else, right? I feel like I missed a "download OS" step, even though I have the ISO for 12.04, and 12.10.

Comment: What are your computer specs... brand, model, graphics card etc. (If you have a radeon or nvidia card try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/257917/14916 )

Answer (score 0):

You should burn a CD or create USB Drive with installation. Then run wubi. After you finish wubi will restart machine. But still Ubuntu is not there in your machine. To complete installation don't remove CD or USB from computer let ubuntu install to continue with it.